# JavaMail: "Remote host closed connection during handshake" while connecting with office365

Tags: ssl, jakarta-mail, office365

I try to connect to office365 mail server with javaMail v1.5.3 (application is deployed on tomcat 6). Im running a thread on startup that is checking for new emails in a loop with one minute sleep. In most cases connection is successfully estabilished and everything works just fine but sometimes I get 
"Remote host closed connection during handshake" error.

The error is caused by

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
```

I have tried sulutions from: 
[How to make Java 6, which fails SSL connection with "SSL peer shut down incorrectly", succeed like Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589880/how-to-make-java-6-which-fails-ssl-connection-with-ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrec)
and [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980218/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handsh) :

adding `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,SSLv3` and -`Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true` to my tomcat environment 
but I didn't get any result. Still - randomly exception occurs.

I enabled debug mode on javax.net and on IMAP connection and get results:
when connection is not estabilishing correctly log looks like this :

```
 DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.3
 DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
 DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
 DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
 DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
 DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
 DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
 DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
 DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
 Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
 %% Client cached [Session-4, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
 %% Try resuming [Session-4, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA] from port 51400
 *** ClientHello, TLSv1
 RandomCookie:  
 GMT: 1435130635 
 bytes = { , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  }
 Session ID:  {66, 20, 0, 0, 123, 9, 142, 72, 150, 39, 215, 34, 63, 169, 129, 23, 25, 182, 88, 196, 86, 27, 216, 191, 117, 196, 37, 118, 229, 8, 9, 64}-
 Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]-
 Compression Methods:  { }
 Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: outlook.office365.com]
 ***-
 [write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 125
 46@CheckMailThread, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 125
 [Raw write]: length = 130
 46@CheckMailThread, received EOFException: error
 46@CheckMailThread, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
 46@CheckMailThread, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
 46@CheckMailThread, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
 [Raw write]: length = 7
 46@CheckMailThread, called closeSocket()
```

and then exception occurs

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Remote host closed connection during handshake;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:733)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    (...)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:953)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:574)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:369)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:117)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:120)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:753)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:696)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
    ... 16 more
```

In other hand in most cases thread is doing ok and the log looks like this:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.3 
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle] 
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384 
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false 
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000 
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
 DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10 
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure 
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true 
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA 
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA 
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA 
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false 
%% Client cached [Session-150, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
 %% Try resuming [Session-150, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA] from port 59183
 *** ClientHello, TLSv1 
RandomCookie:   
GMT: 1435076193  
bytes = { , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , }  
Session ID:   
{241, 61, 0, 0, 224, 114, 43, 139, 255, 64, 232, 7, 209, 90, 5, 63, 63, 117, 33, 66, 215, 35, 48, 83, 131, 211, 38, 151, 73, 232, 6, 120} 
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] 
Compression Methods:  {  
 } 
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: outlook.office365.com] 
*** 
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 125 
46@CheckMailThread, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 125 
[Raw write]: length = 130 
[Raw read]: length = 5 
[Raw read]: length = 3532 
46@CheckMailThread, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 3532 
*** ServerHello, TLSv1 
RandomCookie:   
GMT: 1435076194  
Bytes = { , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , } 
Session ID:   
{112, 39, 0, 0, 59, 34, 200, 120, 31, 23, 110, 30, 10, 37, 236, 213, 46, 233, 201, 3, 253, 223, 81, 109, 188, 218, 33, 164, 33, 127, 27, 55} 
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA 
Compression Method: 0 
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty> 
*** 
%% Initialized:  [Session-151, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
 ** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA 
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 81 
*** Certificate chain (...)
```

And then goes the certificate etc

So I was wonderig what can cause such inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: If it works most of the time but sometimes not it is probably more related to connectivity and server side problems. For instance the server might close the connection on high load etc.  This just happens and there is probably nothing you can do against it. Thus just retry after some time and hope that the problem has gone away.

Comment: You should also consider that outlook.office365.com is not **one** server, but a whole lot of them. So there's the chance one of them is not configured like all the others

Comment: Is your application running on one Tomcat server, or a cluster of Tomcat servers?  If a cluster, maybe they're not all using the same JDK version?  It does look like a cipher suite problem.  You might need to set the [mail.imap.ssl.protocols](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.ssl.protocols) or [mail.imap.ssl.ciphersuites](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.ssl.ciphersuites) properties.  (Use "mail.imaps.*" if you're using the "imaps" protocol.)

Comment: So my application is deployed on a single Tomcat on my computer. I used nslookup to find addresses that office is connecting to and one by one added to my etc/hosts . Every one of them worked just fine on a single request so I figure there is either problem with dropping connection when load is to high like Steffen said or I had "luck" and in that time nslookup returned properly configured server addressed :)